# Обновление приложение без Play Маркета

Tags: android, phonegap, update

Есть android телефон с приложением сделанным через phonegap, как можно обновить это приложение удалённо, без каких либо действий на самом телефоне телефоне?
То есть мы удалённо (на другом устройстве) выполнили какое-то действие и приложение самое скачалось и установилось на телефоне.
Утраивает вариант, как с автоматической проверкой версии раз в промежуток времени, так и обновлением только после отправки запроса (удалённо).
Возможно есть какие-то приложения для этого или это можно реализовать в самом приложении (phonegap)?
Заливать на Play Маркета и ставить авто обновление - не предлагать.

Comment: @D-side , нет, там спрашивается об простой проверкии новой версии и выводе сообщения об этом, а меня интересует именно автоматическое обновление приложения.

Comment: Fair enough. Голос на закрытие отозвал. Отредактируйте вопрос, акцентируйте, что интересует автоматическая установка. Но могу авансом сказать, что без рута (или прав администратора, наверное) "беспилотную установку" вам система не разрешит.

Comment: @Mr_Epic Вы сами написали ответ на Ваш вопрос. "по-тихому" установка пройти не сможет, только через показ диалога с установкой

Comment: @tim_taller но Play Маркета это же как то делает?

Comment: @Mr_Epic у системных приложений привилегии бывают выше.